# Size of an array of a Room Query

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

in my Dao I've defined a Query like this to check whether the database is empty or not:

```
@Query("SELECT * from meal_table LIMIT 1")
suspend fun getAnyMeal(): LiveData<Array<Meal>>
```

Within my populateDatabse function I would like to check, whether any item is inside my database with something like this:

```
suspend fun populateDatabase(mealDao: MealDao) {
    if ((mealDao.getAnyMeal()).size < 1) 
    ...
}
```

Unforunately size doesnt work in this context unless I am doing something wrong.
If someone has a tipp on how to solve this I would apreciate it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unforunately size doesnt work in this context

It is because `getAnyMeal` returns you `LiveData` which has no property named `size`. `LiveData` is an observable object. It means that `LiveData` object you get by calling this method will return **to its observers** (only the ones who "subscribed" to updates) an array of `Meal` objects when this array will be available.

First of all, when you are using `LiveData` with Room you sort of giving Room a signal that you are not requesting a response immediately. LiveData is used when you want to get updates in future that will happen **on change of any object** in DB. Also you may want to use `LiveData` when you want to execute the `SELECT` query asynchronously. It means you call `getAnyMeal` method and it does not block UI thread.

When you are using `suspend` keyword you can remove `LiveData` from return type. When suspend function is executed it will synchronously return you the result.

#### Solution

Update `getAnyMeal()` to the next form or create the new method as it is declared below:

```
@Query("SELECT * from meal_table LIMIT 1")
suspend fun getAnyMeal(): Array<Meal>
```

If you declare `getAnyMeal` method like this you will be able to call `size` property on the return type as it directly returns you an array.

---

[On LiveData with Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data):

> Room doesn't support database access on the main thread unless you've called allowMainThreadQueries() on the builder because it might lock the UI for a long period of time. Asynchronous queries—queries that return instances of LiveData or Flowable—are exempt from this rule because they asynchronously run the query on a background thread when needed.

[Observable queries with LiveData](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-observable) for more info.

Comment: Thank you very much for your in depth explanation, this helped me out!